# Node Install remove some node module

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, npm-install

I'm new on stack overflow and I'm a newbie on development

I created an app with angular, but I have a problem when I try to install a node module with npm install. Some modules are deleted. I looked for solutions on the forum but I did not find a clear solution.

Somebody could tell me how to install a node modules without others being removed please?

thanks a lot

Comment: Typically `npm install` uninstalls all currently installed packages which are not listed as dependency (or a dependency of a dependency) in `package.json`. Make sure, every package you install, is also listed in `package.json`

Comment: ok thanks ... I try it

Comment: Please add detail. What is in your package.json? What gets added or removed. What is the exact command you are running. Please read [mre].

Comment: for example "npm install --save ngx-mask" ... I have some error ......                     
 npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/animations@^8.1.1
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/cdk@~8.2.3
npm ERR!     Missing: @angular/cli@^8.1.1 ..................................................

Answer (score -1):

If you add some specific then no need to run npm install

Nom install acan whole package.json
Please use below
npm install (package-name)

Please comment is helpful or correct